# RxSwift Buffer Performance

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Is there a form of `buffer` that doesn't continuously poll with a timer? Performance really takes a hit because of it. Ideally, `buffer` would wait *n* seconds before producing values and then not set a new timer until receiving a new event.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at a non-polling buffer:

```
extension Observable {

    private struct Buffered<T> {
        let lastFlush: Date
        let remaining: RxTimeInterval
        let value: [T]
    }

    func buffered(delay: RxTimeInterval) -> Observable<[Element]> { return
        scan(
            Buffered<Element>(
                lastFlush: Date(),
                remaining: delay,
                value: []
            )
        ) { sum, x in
            let latest = Date()
            let isExpired = latest > (sum.lastFlush + delay)
            let adjusted = isExpired ? latest : sum.lastFlush
            return Buffered<Element>(
                lastFlush: adjusted,
                remaining: isExpired
                           ? delay
                           : delay - latest.timeIntervalSince(adjusted)
                ,
                value: isExpired ? [x] : sum.value + [x]
            )
        }
        .flatMapLatest {
            Observable
                .just($0.value)
                .delay(
                    $0.remaining,
                    scheduler: MainScheduler.instance
                )
                //.ignoringCompletions()
        }
    }

    public func ignoringCompletions() -> Observable { return
         concat(Observable.never())
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ignoringCompletions` is useless as an inner sequence won't complete the outer sequence: when `timer` completes and a new event arrives at the `flatMapLatest`, a new `timer` will start.

Comment: Wouldn't the first completion of the timer cause the outer sequence to also complete and prevent further events. I've paired this operator with a Behavior subject in my project and so that feature is necessary in my scenario. I've tried appending the `.ignoreCompletions` outside of the `flatMapLatest` closure to make the `buffered(delay)` operator more general but that approach didn't successfully prevent completions.

Comment: No, only an error event would complete the outer sequence. You can add `.debug()` operator before the `flatMapLatest`, on the inner sequence and after the  `flatMapLatest` to see the lifecycle and see the difference with or without `ignoreCompletions`